# in Python, are statements objects?

Tags: python, object, if-statement, reference, conditional-statements

As far as I understand, everything in python is an object or a reference. 
For example: in `x = 1`, `x` is a reference to the integer object `1`. If I write `print type(x)`, then Python will tell me the object that x is referencing is an integer.

So what about statements such as `if`?

if I try `print type(if)`, unsurprisingly, I get a syntax error. I can speculate on why this is the case. Maybe `if` is a static method of a class, or maybe it has somehow been weirdly defined as non returnable, etc. I just don't know.

Ultimately, I suspect that `if` has nothing to do with an object or a reference. However, that would surely go against the idea of everything being an object or a reference?

Comment: No, statements are not objects.

Comment: Statements are the recipe of your program. They're read, [tokenized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html), [parsed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), and [compiled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) to [bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html). They're not objects or functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When they say "everything is an object or a reference" they are referring specifically to data. So this naturally does not apply to statements. Of course, all expressions will result in data. For example `a == b` is `<class 'bool'>` because it is an expression.

There are some languages where `if` is an expression but python is not one of them.

Comment: Right ok, that makes a lot more sense. I just tested print type(a ==b), to confirm you were right, and I had a bit of a wow moment haha when it did indeed, as you said it would, print out <type 'bool'>. Thanks a lot!